# get value from array pointer to pointer of a struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct

Im expecting to get the value of the pointer that pp is pointing to

this is my struct

```
struct game
{
    int rank;
    int year;
    char *name;
    char *platform;
    char *genre;
    char *publisher;

    // sales below represented in millions
    float NA_sales;
    float EU_sales;
    float JP_sales;
    float other_sales;
    float global_sales;
} Game;
```

i got the array of pointer to pointer as

```
struct Game **arr[MAX_NUM]; // max num is 100
```

and i assign

```
arr[counter] = &new_game; // new_game is calloc as struct game *new_game = calloc(1, sizeof(struct game));
```

i tried with

```
arr[counter]->publisher
```

but it return as

```
'*arr[counter]' is a pointer; did you mean to use '->'?
         printf("%s", arr[counter]->new_game->publisher);
```

Comment: Using an array of pointer to pointer doesn't seem to make much sense here. It should probably be an array of structs or an array of pointers to structs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the error here is that you have an extra level of indirection that the compiler isn't expecting which gives you an error with a bad suggestion.  Since you have a pointer to pointer to array, the type of `arr[counter]` is still a pointer to pointer to struct.  Here is how you access struct member via a pointer (as you know):

```
struct Foo* bar;
bar->a = 0;
```

But if that was a pointer to pointer, we need to dereference the first pointer to be able to use `->` correctly:

```
struct Foo** bar;
(*bar)->a = 0;
```

Another way to look at it is `bar->a` is nothing more than syntax sugar for `(*bar).a`. You have an extra level of indirection, so without the `->`, you would need `(**bar).a`.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why you want to have so many levels of indirection.

To access using pointer

```
typedef struct game
{
    int rank;
    int year;
    char *name;
    char *platform;
    char *genre;
    char *publisher;

    // sales below represented in millions
    float NA_sales;
    float EU_sales;
    float JP_sales;
    float other_sales;
    float global_sales;
} Game;

/* ..... */
/* how to access */

int main(void) {
    Game **arr[100];
    
    Game *newGame = calloc(1, sizeof(*newGame));
    arr[0] = &newGame;
    
    printf("%f", arr[0][0] -> NA_sales);
    printf("%f", (*arr[0]) -> NA_sales);
    printf("%f", (**arr) -> NA_sales);
```

Comment: Doing it like this will likely lead to errors when `newGame` goes out of scope.

Comment: @interjay it is about **access** syntax, not scopes or UBs

Comment: @interjay Heap memory? Out of scope? You're inferring quite a bit there.  I undid his `-1` there is not one scope on this whole page.

Comment: @Jason `newGame` (the pointer itself, not the value it points to) is a local variable and not on the heap. Storing `&newGame` in an array and then accessing that array after `newGame` goes out of scoope will cause undefined behavior. Even if this answer tries supposed to only answer how to access the pointer, it needs at least a disclaimer for the dangerous code.

Comment: @interjay assume that it is `main`. `return` terminates program and your problem is blown in the wind

Comment: @0___________ That's not a very realistic assumption. In real code arrays are usually assigned either in a function or a loop. In both cases the variable would go out of scope quickly. Since this is a beginner question, putting code like this in an answer will mislead people.